# WPF Animating a Run element to flash

Tags: wpf, animation

This is kind of a weird problem I am having right now.  What I am trying to do is animate a Run element to essentially flash/blink.  The parent is a Hyperlink which contains multiple Inlines of type Run and Image.  Now I am trying to animate the Foreground color of the element but it does not seem to work.

Here is my code for a hyperlink.

```
 CallbackHyperLink callbackLink = new CallbackHyperLink();
 ToolTipService.SetShowDuration(callbackLink, 3600000);
 ToolTipService.SetInitialShowDelay(callbackLink, 0);
 callbackLink.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Magenta);                        // Default text color of the link

 callbackLink.TextDecorations = null;                            // Disable the underline until mouse over
 callbackLink.ToolTip = f.Tooltip;                               // Set the tooltip string

DoubleAnimation opacityAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
opacityAnim.From = 1.0;
opacityAnim.To = 0.0;
opacityAnim.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
opacityAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BlinkDurationOff);
opacityAnim.AutoReverse = true;
_blinkAnimation.Children.Add(opacityAnim);

Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnim, callbackLink.Foreground);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnim, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.OpacityProperty));

_blinkAnimation.Stop();
_blinkAnimation.Begin();
```

So that gets put in a storyboard which get fired.  However the foreground is not getting animated and I am not seeing any warnings that im trying to animate something I shouldn't.  Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnim, callbackLink); 
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnim, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
```

**Edit** full working example with a TextBlock [stolen from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock callbackLink = new TextBlock();
    callbackLink.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    callbackLink.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    callbackLink.Text = "Test";
    this.Content = callbackLink;

    NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());

    var b = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Magenta);
    callbackLink.Foreground = b;
    this.RegisterName("MyAnimatedBrush", b);

    DoubleAnimation opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    opacityAnimation.To = 0.0;
    opacityAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
    opacityAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
    opacityAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(opacityAnimation, "MyAnimatedBrush");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
        opacityAnimation, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.OpacityProperty));
    Storyboard mouseLeftButtonDownStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    mouseLeftButtonDownStoryboard.Children.Add(opacityAnimation);
    callbackLink.MouseEnter += delegate(object sender2, MouseEventArgs ee)
    {
        mouseLeftButtonDownStoryboard.Begin(this, true);
    };

    callbackLink.MouseLeave += delegate(object sender2, MouseEventArgs ee)
    {
        mouseLeftButtonDownStoryboard.Stop(this);
    };


}
```

Comment: Not sure why but it does not seem to work for me.  Will keep trying to see if there is something weird with my setup.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it working.  Did not work directly but found a way around my issues. My biggest problem is that my storyboard is more global, ie multiple of these hyperlinks get put into the storyboard.

Comment: Perhaps you should update the question to make useful for others searching SO/the web with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also another way to link to the foreground opacity call without registering the name of the brush is the following.

```
    Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnim, callbackLink);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnim, new PropertyPath("Foreground.Opacity"));
```

This seems to finally work for me.  Still tweaking my solution as I am doing a lot of Stop/Begin calls on the animation which I believe is not good way of doing things.